# How to make the font size of the caption of tikzfigure environment larger?

Tags: tikzposter

I am wondering how to make the caption larger in the tikzfigure environment within tikzposter. It is showing up rather small and I would like it to be more readable.

I tried using \Large in the caption but it did not scale the figure designation with it. Example code below.

```
\begin{tikzfigure}[\Large FigureCaption]
    Figure
\end{tikzfigure}
```

So I got something like this as an equivalent result:

```
{\footnotesize Fig.1}{\Large FigureCaption}
```

Any ideas how to make both the figure label and the caption text scale together?

Comment: Could you show is a complete but minimal example to work with? Complete means from `\documentclass{}` to `\end{document}` and minimal means with all packages, definitions and text you need to show the problem, but only these. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: The caption is not small.  The default paper size is about 33in by 47in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, the text as well as the font size is hard coded in the class file. You can easily copy that part from the class file and customize it to your needs. Following the original definition with just the size changed.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{tikzfigure}[1][]{
  \def \rememberparameter{#1}
  \vspace{10pt}
  \refstepcounter{figurecounter}
  \begin{center}
  }{
    \ifx\rememberparameter\@empty
    \else %nothing
    \\[10pt]
    {\huge Fig.~\thefigurecounter: \rememberparameter}
    \fi
  \end{center}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\block{Walzing Wombat}{%
    Wombats love the walz, ducks dance dixie

    \begin{tikzfigure}[This is a nice caption]
        \rule{.5\linewidth}{5cm}
    \end{tikzfigure}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll introduce some improvements, more font sizes available, fige and table environments with proper captions and the availability of subcaptions and so on. If it won't make it to the original project and CTAN, the modified version will still be on bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{poiuyt}
\author{qsdfg}
\date{\today}
\institute{azerty}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=Large}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{A figure}
{
    \begin{tikzfigure}
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{image.pdf}
    \end{tikzfigure}
    \captionof{figure}{azer}
}

\end{document}
```

should work. You need to use the caption package and to put the fontsize in the caption setup line.

Comment: I tried it and no size option I put in changes the font size in the poster.

Comment: You should give me a minimal example like I did. You should als verify if for you the above given code doesn't work. For me it worked well. I edited it to fit to the tikzposter and tikzfigure environement.